# No error highlighting with Kotlin in Android Studio 3.3 [Android Studio Issue]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, syntax-highlighting, android-studio-3.3

I have no error highlighting in code (see screenshot below) Android Studio 3.3 (Ubuntu), but I have a notification about the error on scrollbar, in the project tree and on mouse hover over the bad code.

[image: No error in code, but error on scrollbar]

**Additional info**
My studio64.vmoptions:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
```

**Suggested solutions, which is not working:**

1. Invalidate cache and restart
2. Mark directory with the code as sources
3. Clean & Rebuild
4. Set light theme in Android Studio
5. Increase memory size using -Xmx